# wpf binding not working after source initializes

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, bind

I'm trying to create a binding from code. MSDN gives this example:

```
MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);      
Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyDataProperty");  
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;    
myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);
```

This way it works all right, I'm using `INotifyPropertyChanged` as I should.My problem is, after setting up the binding, if I do this:

```
MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);
```

then the binding wont work with my new object. The visible values wont update anymore. I guess I should add my binding source in a different, dynamic way.

Comment: I believe you should show us how the MyData class is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are recreating the data source so you will need to update the binding straight afterwards:

```
MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
```

You might have to call `SetBinding` again as well.

Comment: Isn't there a way to work around this?what if I do it this way?
    MyData myDataObject = new MyData(DateTime.Now);      
    Binding myBinding = new Binding("myDataObject.MyDataProperty");  
    myText.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, myBinding);

Comment: @Wtf1sh - no. You are changing your data source. The binding is on the old one. You need to recreate it on the new one.

Answer (score 1):

The binding is not taking care about the Source, which has to be (very) stable instead. What you can change is the instance path, specified by the PropertyPath and/or the Binding constructor argument.